# Freelook using Xbox 360 Controller on PC?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, battlefield-3

I've been configuring my Xbox 360 controller to use for flying jets in BF3 for PC, and it works great except for one shortcoming. I bound the buttons to be the same as the 360 controls (Down on the dpad to enter freelook, right stick to move around), but the looking motion is *very* slow. **Is there a way to set up freelook to move at a useful rate using this setup?**

Here's a video of me trying to freelook with the right thumbstick pushed as far as it will go: